# Property 'label' is missing in type '{ handleClick: () => void; }' but required in type '{ handleClick: () => void; label: string; }'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, jsx, next.js

I am having issues while describing the types of my props. I am getting an error on the following lines of code:

```
 <PostButton handleClick={props.upvote}/>
  <PostButton2 handleClick={props.downvote}/>
```

The error is:

> Property 'label' is missing in type '{ handleClick: () => void; }' but
>   required in type '{ handleClick: () => void; label: string;
>   }'.ts(2741) Comments.tsx(62, 55): 'label' is declared here.

When I try to remove 'label: string; ' from my function props, it throws an error stating:

> Property 'label' does not exist on type '{ handleClick: () => void;
>   }'.

Here is my code:

```
function Button(props: { handleClick: () => void;  }) {

    let style = {
        paddingRight: 100,

    };
    return (
        <div>
            <button style={style} onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
                {props.label}

                    PostButton
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the function PostButton you are trying to print `{props.label}` which doesn't exist in the props, try removing the `props: { handleClick: () => void;  }` and go with just `function PostButton()`. I see too many handlers that are assigned to do nothing, why not remove those as well and clean the code.

**Better Solution:**
If you want to keep on using `{props.label}` then just add it when calling the function like this: `<PostButton handleClick={props.upvote} label="this is a label, it can be left blank"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Both your `PostButton` is using `{props.label}` in `return`, so you have to pass label as props

```
function PostButton(props: { handleClick: () => void; title: string  }) {....}

<PostButton handleClick={props.upvote} title="titlePostButton"/>

<PostButton2 handleClick={props.downvote} title="titlePostButton2"/>
```